# DownloadManager does not broadcast intent, when external storage has insufficient space

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I want to download file with `DownloadManager`.
And I can do that with sufficient space.

When external storage has sufficient space, I can download file properly and receive broadcast intent with `ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE`.

But, when external storage has insufficient space, file downloaded with size of 0 byte. And I can not receive broadcast intent. No message about broadcast intent appears in debug console as well.

Why was that? and, how can I receive `ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` with `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE`?

I want to show the error message, when user has insufficient space.